# Remove url number pagination on wordpress blog post

Tags: php, wordpress, seo, canonical-link, yoast

Is this possible to remove paging on blog post
our client is using wordpress yoast SEO

**Example : Blog result page 1**

```
http://example.com/author/kamesh/
```

**Example : Blog result page 2**

```
http://example.com/author/kamesh/page/2
```

I want to remove **page/2** hope someone can help.

Comment: Just so best path can be suggested, can you please tell why you need pagination removed? You do not want those pages indexed? or you want to show all posts for any given author on just one page? Or you just want to show latest x posts on the page and no pagination ...

Comment: @Mohsin, I wanted to remove because i have use scrolling pegging nation , do not want to keep dummy URL : http://example.com/author/kamesh/page/2

Comment: this will be applied for canonical, when ever you are in author/kamesh/page/2 the canonical must be read as author/kamesh